# Angular ngprime table using 2 json

Tags: angular

I am new to ngprime and facing below issue. I get 2 json one for labels for first column and second json had data for second and third columns. data for second and third column need to displayed basis on id from json 1. Eg. json one has id firstName and displayname as Firstname. I need to refer id from json one and search for same id in json 2 and display values in column 2 and 3.

I want to achieve this using ngPrime p-table and not even able to start. Below is the json to be used and output to be achieved.

I tried searching similar questions not nothing helped me. please help me with example

```js
var json1 = [
  {id:'firstName', displayname:'First Name'},
   {id:'lastName', displayname:'Last Name'},
    {id:'age', displayname:'Age'},
     {id:'city', displayname:'City'},
      {id:'state', displayname:'State'}
      ];
      
var json2 = [
    {'firstName':'abc', 'age': 23, 'state':'MH', 'lastName': 'sharma', 'city': 'Mumbai'},
    {'firstName':'xyz', 'age': 35, 'state':'TL', 'lastName': 'Verma', 'city': 'Hyderabad'}
];
```

```html
<!-- Need output as below using ngPrime <p-table><p-table> -->


<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Record 1</th>
      <th>Record 1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>xyz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Name</td>
      <td>sharma</td>
      <td>verma</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Age</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>35</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>City</td>
      <td>Mumbai</td>
      <td>Hyderabad</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>State</td>
      <td>MH</td>
      <td>TL</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Did you check [ng-prime table doc](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table) ?

Comment: I am confused how to pass this 2 jsons